# How use or enable Tor Circuit when it is in Remote Control (Selenium)?

Tags: selenium, security, tor

Actually I managed control Tor Browser with Selenium, but I'd realised that Tor circuits (change of IP's) isn't enable. So exist a way to enable it? Or use the new feature called (New Identity) form code.

My enviroment is Python 3.7, tbselenium 0.4.2 and Tor Browser 9.0.2, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example script on how to use Tor with the chrome webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

#tor
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

link = #some_url
prox='socks5://127.0.0.1:9150' #This connects Selenium to the Tor Port which then connects to a Tor network

while True:

    with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller: #this is how you get a new Identity!
        controller.authenticate()
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % prox) #sets conncection to your 9150 port aka Tor Network

    #chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') #opens headless browser
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('*path to your driver file*', chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(link)
    #perform selenium stuff
```

You will need to install the `stem` library which is basically Tor API for Python. You also will have to edit the `torrc` file. [Here](https://www.sylvaindurand.org/use-tor-with-python/) you can read how to do all that.

Comment: Thanks! I can start a instance of chrome but I don't know why that instance hasn't Internet, but obviously there is Internet in my computer. What's happened?

Comment: I found the error, you write 9150 like the port but is 9050. But no problem, thanks for the code